# Uploading an Image to Google Cloud Storage using file.save(). All seems successful but image is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Google Cloud Storage to be used on a website. I'm taking a screenshot from apiflash and receiving the image data.

With the image data, I'm then trying to save this to Google Cloud using file.save()

Everything is working in the process other than the fact the image is not displaying.

Here is the image in the Gcloud storage dashboard.

[image]

Error message it's throwing out

[image: Error Message]

Here is the code for the upload. Am I missing something? It's giving a success and the upload works, there is just no image. The image coming back is type jpeg and I've tried using .jpg and also receiving a png but that gives the same errors.

The response body is just the image data and nothing else.. Lots of this...

```
0\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05(\x00\x01J\x00\x00R�\x00\x14�\x00\x05+��"
```

```
        request(options, function (error, response) {
          if (error) throw new Error(error);
          const content = response.body;
          const file = bucket.file(`${gameid}.jpeg`);
          file.save(
            content,
            {
              resumable: false,
              public: true,
              contentType: response.headers['content-type'],
            },
            (err) => {
              if (!err) {
                console.log('success');
              } else {
                console.log('ERROR', err);
              }
            }
          );
        });
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `response.headers['content-type']`?

Comment: Hey. Headers seem OK.
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)',
    date: 'Fri, 29 Jan 2021 23:03:16 GMT',
    'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
    'content-length': '464247',

Comment: One question: shouldn't the `response` object be named `request`?
The issue must be in the way the file content is supplied in the `body`. I tested your code using `Multer` to supply the file (as shown in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage#application_code)) and worked correctly. How are you supplying the file data in the body? Could you share the code that does that in your app?